# Show hyperlink in message in UIAlerController in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I want to show some text with hyperlink as a message in UIAlertController in Objective-c.
If I click on that hyperlink it should redirect me to open the link in Safari.

I do not want to use in third party libraries.

Any Idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: From Apple's docs: *`The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.`* You should create your own controller (to present modally).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to show it as hyperlink. Either you can add your own message dialog or you can add a button in your UIAlertController to open a hyperlink.

Step 1. Get the URL from your message string

```
NSURL *url;

NSString *string = @"This is a sample of a http://example.com/index.html sentence with a URL within it.";
    NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
      if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
        url = [match URL];
        NSLog(@"found URL: %@", url);
      }
    }
```

Step 2. Display your alert message

```
UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@“Message”
                                                 message:@"Would you like to open link?”
                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                    
                    
                    
                    UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                                actionWithTitle:@“Open using Safari” Link
                                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                                                            if ([app canOpenURL:url])
                                                            {               

                                                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                                                        //completion codes here
                                                    }];
                                                            }



                      
                          }];
                    
                    UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                                               actionWithTitle:@"No"
                                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                   //Handle no, thanks button
                                               }];
                    
                    [alert addAction:yesButton];
                    [alert addAction:noButton];
                    
                    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```